# With MVP there is no need for the Controller as in MVC?

Tags: http, model-view-controller, design-patterns, web, mvp

I understand that in MVP the presenter and the view call each other to coordinate events and display the data from the model. So the View can have no knowledge of the model (right?)

So... my questions are two actually.

1. Is MVP suitable for traditional web applications or just works for ajax web apps? Since the   traditional web paradigm is composed by the view submitting forms to a servlet.
2. In MVP there is no need for a controller? And... well, the presenter is not a controller after all?

In my old web applications I was using a more complex approach to MVC which can be represented by this:

[image]

This is also a variation of the "redirect after post" web pattern. But I always had a special Controller as a cap for the jsp page (or other template technology), which has the duty to take the url parameter (usually an ID) and load the object to be displayed by the html template.
The "cap controller" is strictly associated to a specific view, while the Action Controller just executes an operation and select the next view, redirecting to its cap.

This "cap controller" is somehow similar to the concept of the "Presenter" in the MVP?

In MVP, the Presenter also handles the events, in my understanding. In MVP the role of the presenter covers the role of the action controller plus the "cap controller" above?

Or is this a kind of hybrid (MVPC)?

Comment: You could start by reading the definitive publication on [MVP](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf). It would explain some of it to you. But in the nutshell - yes, the presenter is essentially something that replaces the classical controller. It has different responsibilities, therefore - it has a different name to avoid the confusion. Also, you have to understand that classical MVC is not really possible on web. The closest we have is Model2MVC. Oh .. and then there is Rails & clones, which marketing people call "mvc", but which really isn't.

Comment: I'm new to MVP in fact. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the presenter is the one in control of everything. It takes a request, tells the model what to do, and then passes the result on to the view for display. It's not a circular procedure. The model reports back to the presenter. At least in the Passive View variant.